Is it still not possible to open Excel from a Word Add-In?
Is there still not any way to open Excel from an Office.js Word add-in and perform actions in Excel?
I found a similar question from 2020 here: Creating Word document from Excel Add-In with Office.js. The answer was "no" then, but I was hoping maybe things had changed.
Thanks!

I'm not at all certain about the office.js part,  but for ages now you could trigger Excel from Word by embedding an Excel Object inside a Word document.  Activating that object would put you into Excel and moving the current location back out of the object would return you to Word.  Maybe you can make use of that here...

Thanks, Chris. I'm actually trying to create a Word add-in that will enable the user to export some elements of the Word doc to a spreadsheet. (That add-in creates the spreadsheet and exports the elements automatically.) I've got this working with a COM add-in, but I'm trying to convert the COM add-in into an O365 add-in using Office.js.

You could look into using something Excel.JS vs trying to use the Office.JS API

No. Office Js seems designed for web use, where each document is independent. You can create but can’t manipulate an Excel document from within Excel, let alone from within Word.
COM Addins remain the most useful extensibility option for many, many use cases.
